# No SMS notifications on Windows 10 PC anymore

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cortana, notifications, messaging, windows-10

I used to get SMS notifications on my Windows 10 PC from my Lumia 950 Windows 10 Mobile (both always updated to the latest version).

I've checked the Windows 10 Mobile settings and the messaging notifications are on.

What else should I check?

Comment: Do reminders set on your PC come up on your phone still?

Answer (score 3):

You should check the following:

• Internet connection is steady on both devices

• Cortana is active and the settings for message notifications are correct on both devices. (You can check them here: Cortana>Notebook>Settings>Sync messages)

• You're using the same Microsoft account on both devices. (Settings>Your email and accounts>Email)

Hope this helps! If it was useful, give me an upvote!

Comment: I have no Settings inside Cortana>Notebook> neither on the Win10 PC nor on the Win10 Lumia 950 phone